# jquery transfer effect holding css at end

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel

So I am making an app that utilizes the effect("transfer") from the query ui. Everything is working. But at the end of the animation the css tag that belongs to the effect .ui-effects-transfer just vanishes. I'd like it to stay on the page.

Is this possible?

here is my code javascript code.

```
  <script>
@foreach  ($stimuli['comparison'] as $stimulus)
    @if($stimuli['sample'][0] == $stimulus)

$("#sample").effect("transfer", {to: $("#{{ $stimulus }}")}, 9000);

        @endif
@endforeach


</script>
```

**EDIT**

So my instinct would be to make a second div for the css. and basically postiion it manually at the end of the animation. But I was wondering if there was a better and easier way? Because I want to keep element the same size as how the transfer is handling that css content image.

**CSS**

```
    .ui-effects-transfer {

    background-image :url("http://images.clipartpanda.com/finger-clipart-pointing-finger-md.png");
    opacity: .8;
    margin-top: 125px;
    z-index: 5 !important; 
  }
```

**Issue**
http://jsfiddle.net/qq8q7357/3/

That is the issue I am.

During animation the picture is above everything. I want it to end by leaving the picture exactly where it is on top of the div rather then having set as a background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the functions complete method to add the class back to the element after the animation is complete. [Here is the documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/effect/)

Jquery UI

```
 $("#sample").effect("transfer", {to: $("#{{ $stimulus }}")}, 9000,function(){
       $('#{{ $stimulus }}').addClass('ui-effects-transfer');
 });
```

EDIT:

```
.ui-effects-transfer {
   background-image :url("http://images.clipartpanda.com/finger-clipart-pointing-finger-md.png") no-repeat;
   opacity: .8;
   z-index: 5 !important;
   background-size:20px 20px; //hand size
   // Use background postion not margin to move the image;
   background-position: 0px 125px;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that my css for the transfer animation   background-image :url("http://images.clipartpanda.com/finger-clipart-pointing-finger-md.png"); puts the picture in the background while during the animation its above everything. Which I prefer. but other than that all works!

Comment: the main problem is actually when the animation ends, then the class actually goes into the $this and I want it to stay on top without changing the other <div> elements at all.

Comment: the same issue is happening. the class enters the table entirely, as a background picture. of that table element, also resizing the table element, and changing the location of the picture. See my edit for my css.

Comment: I don't understand, The effect works for me [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qq8q7357/)

Comment: It isn't that. The issue is that my div actually has a picture in it. When the effect happens the effect is on the picture of the div. But at the end,, it gets included as a background picture. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/qq8q7357/3/

I also edited the main thread to show this

Comment: Honestly I think the problem is in using the addclass. Because I don't want to be adding the class to the given div, rather I want that class to be absiolutely on top of the div as its on thing. I just need to simply position it specifically on top of that div. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Here, I think I finally understand what you need.[jsfiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/qq8q7357/4/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95770/discussion-between-magnetwd-and-jp-foster).